# How to add a bottom border to a table with colored cells

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to add a bottom border to each cell.

I've tried this code, but it resets the table colors:
cell.visible_edges = 'B'

```
# Read the Excel file
excel_file = "/path"
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Filter out rows (axis = 0) and columns (axis = 1) with all NaN values
df = df.dropna(axis=0, how='all')
df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')

# Create a table-like visualization using matplotlib
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 10))
ax.axis('off')  # Turn off the axis

# Plot the table with colored cells, without cell borders and without headers
tab = ax.table(cellText=df.values, cellLoc='center', loc='center')

columns_to_adjust = [0, 1]  # List of column indices to adjust
for i in range(len(df.iloc[:, 0])):
    for col_index in columns_to_adjust:
        cell = tab[(i + 0, col_index)] # Loop through each non-empty cell in both columns
        cell_text = cell.get_text().get_text() # Get text from the cell
        cell.get_text().set_horizontalalignment('left') # Left alignment
        cell.set_height(0.04) # Set the height
        cell = tab[(i + 0, 0)] # Loop through each non-empty cell in column 1
        cell.set_width(0.45) # Set width
        if "ABC" in cell_text:
            cell.get_text().set_color('white')  # Set font color to white
            cell.set_facecolor('blue') # Set background color to blue
        cell.PAD = 0.025 # Adjust spacing between the beginning of the cell and the text
        cell = tab[(i + 0, 1)] # Loop through each non-empty cell in column 2   
        cell.set_width(0.035)  # Set width
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the `pandas.DataFrame` with a `numpy.array` containing some arbitrary data.

There seems to be a bug within matplotlib across multiple releases (I tested v3.5.1 and v3.7.2). The actual problem is not to add borders on colored cells but to get the cell colors rendered correctly, when you are not using cell borders on all four sides.

Here is the corresponding discussion on github:
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/20100

You can create a workaround by drawing the same table twice:

- table 1 with colors and `edges = 'BTLR'` and line width set to zero
- table 2 with your desired value for `edges`

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

## generate some data + colors to display
sample_data = np.array([
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    ['g', 'h', 'i']])
sample_colors = np.array([
    ['#444444', '#555555', '#666666'],
    ['#777777', '#FF00FF', '#999999'],
    ['#AAAAAA', '#BBBBBB', '#CCCCCC']])

## create subplot
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.axis('off')  # Turn off the axis

## create table1 -> cell colors
table1 = ax.table(
    cellText=sample_data,
    cellColours=sample_colors, ## configure cell colors
    cellLoc='center',
    loc='center',
    edges = 'BTLR') ## necessary to render the cell colors

## set linewidth of table1 to zero (invisible cell borders)
for x in table1.properties()['celld'].values():
    x.set(linewidth=0)

## create table2 -> cell borders
table2 = ax.table(
    cellText=sample_data,
    cellLoc='center',
    loc='center',
    edges = 'B') ## actual cell borders (bottom-top-left-right)

## display result
plt.show()
```

In case you have to do this repeatedly, you may use a function to execute the workaround for you:

```
def mpl_table_colors_fixed(ax, **kwargs):
    edges_tmp = kwargs["edges"]
    kwargs["edges"] = 'BTLR'
    
    tab1 = ax.table(**kwargs)
    for x in tab1.properties()['celld'].values():
        x.set(linewidth=0)

    kwargs["edges"] = edges_tmp
    tab2 = ax.table(**kwargs)
    
    return tab2
```

... and then call it like this:

```
table1 = mpl_table_colors_fixed(
    ax,
    cellText=sample_data,
    cellColours=sample_colors,
    cellLoc='center',
    loc='center',
    edges = 'B')
```

Comment: When I add edges = 'B' to ax.table, the color Blue I assign later on disappears.

Comment: Seems weird, but is there a specific reason why you cannot assign the colors upfront when you create the table?

Comment: When I assign colors upfront without mentioning the edges, the colors work fine:

colors = [['#FFFFFF' if cell != "ABC" else '#ADD8E6' for cell in row] for row in df.values]

tab = ax.table(cellText=df.values, cellLoc='center', loc='center', cellColours=colors)


.But when I add edges = 'B' to ax.table, the colors disappear.

Comment: I think I found the issue (known bug in matplotlib). Please check if the modified answer solves your problem.